# Python struct format character sizes, why is it bigger than it should be?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, binary

Simple question if do the following:

```
import struct
struct.calcsize("6cHcBHIIQ")
```

returns 32 when I believe it should be 28.

By doing the following (missing the Q):

```
import struct
struct.calcsize("6cHcBHII")
```

it returns 20, which is what I would expect.

and doing:

```
import struct
struct.calcsize("Q")
```

returns 8, which is correct.

Why does adding the Q onto the top one result in 12 extra bytes being expected instead of 8?

Python 3, windows machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Just an update to this question: same behavior can be reproduced on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alignment.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-alignment for more details.

Try `struct.calcsize("=6cHcBHIIQ")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also minimize the size by realigning these in a better way:

```
struct.calcsize("QIIHHB6cc")
```

yields `28`,you should generally expect padding to be the culprit in any struct size issues. See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) for a good answer on why struct sizes might sometimes be larger than what they seem.

Comment: Thanks for this. Id I'm unpacking bytes from a file then the format string would need to be in the correct order though would it not?